# How can I center items in Slick Carousel?

Tags: javascript, carousel, slick.js

I'm using the [Slick Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), but there's one layout itch I can't scratch.  When I have fewer items than the carousel can display at once, they're left-justified.  I'd like them to be centered.  For example, with `slidesToShow` equal 3 and only 2 items, I get

```
-------------------
 IIIII IIIII
-------------------
```

when what I want is

```
-------------------
    IIIII IIIII
-------------------
```

or if there's only 1 item:

```
-------------------
       IIIII
-------------------
```

I've tried setting `centerMode`, but that's a completely different effect.

Is there a way to get the effect I want?  It needs to handle `slidesToShow` being reduced by responsive breakpoints.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A quick inspection of the carousel's DOM shows that the items are put in an element with the class `slick-track`. It is possible to center the items by modifying the margins of that element:

```
.slick-track {
    margin:auto;
}
```

Demo in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fcnvotjg/5/).

Note that the carousel in the demo sometimes stops working correctly when being resized while the last item is active but that happens regardless of this CSS modification.

Comment: That looks like it, except I used `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` instead.

Comment: I had this problem and I had to use `margin: 0;` to get it centered

Answer (score 8):

Putting `margin:0 auto;` on the `<img>` tag worked for me.

E.g.,

```
<div class="items">
    <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/25x50" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/25x50" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/25x50" />
    </div>
<div>
```

CSS

```
.items { background:red; }
.items img { margin:0 auto; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cegor9j2/

Comment: Do you know how to get this to work if the number of slides in the carousel is less than the slidesToShow parameter?